# Adding objects to an array to my shopping cart in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a form that takes an order from customers and I am using React Redux to manage my state. There is an array of object named items where I add the items of the order to it. Every item is an object of 4 properties (name, quantity, price, instructions). And here is how I handle my form :

```
<div className="items-header-container">
                    <h3 className="items-form-header">ITEM #{i + 1}</h3>
                    <Button onClick={() => removeItem(i)}>Remove Item</Button>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
                        <Label >Item Name</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="name" onChange={setFormValue} value={form.items.name} />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
                        <Label >QTY</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="quantity" onChange={setFormValue} value={form.items.quantity} />
                    </FormGroup>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
                        <Label >Price</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="price" onChange={setFormValue} value={form.items.price} />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup className="col-md-6">
                        <Label >Special Instructions</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="special_instructions" onChange={setFormValue} value={form.items.special_instructions} />
                    </FormGroup>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the redux action that takes the input :

```
export function setFormValue(field) {
    console.log("FIELD", field.target.value)
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: types.SET_FORM_VALUE, payload: field })
    };
}
```

This is my reducer function where I am handling the part of the items in the form:

```
 if (action.payload.target.name === "items") {
                let cloneditems = [...state.form.items];
                cloneditems.push(action.payload.target.value);
                return {
                    ...state,
                    form: {
                        ...state.form,
                        items: cloneditems
                    }
                };
            }
```

What I am planning to do is to add an item object and push it to the items array every time I add an item with its details in my form. Yet, it adds them outside the items array not inside as an object. Can anyone help me with this part as it consumes a lot of time and I cannot make it? Here is a link to my project if you want to have a look :

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-williamson-nvqx9?file=/src/redux/reducer.js

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a nutshell what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: @BARNOWL I want simply to add an object with item details to the array which is called "Items" that has -in the end- all items that were added.

Comment: So in the `items` array you want to add item details within the `items` array correct ?

Comment: in your reducer.... what is `itemDetails` referenced as ?

Comment: @BARNOWL I have an array of items and I want to simply add each item to this array as an object of 4 properties "name, price, quantity, instructions"

Comment: ok i think i have an idea now.

Comment: @BARNOWL How is that possible?!

Comment: I will look into it.. cause im still need to have an idea what you're doing already.

Comment: @BARNOWL If you need more explanation, pls let me know. Also, taking a look at the code through the link might help too.

Comment: I see "users"    `if (action.payload.target.name === "users")`  not  `if (action.payload.target.name === "items") {`..

Comment: is that a mistake ?

Comment: @BARNOWL yes it is a typo. I fixed it you can check again. Still not working as expected!

Comment: i understand, im looking into it currently give some time. but its supposed to be "users"  not "items"  correct  ?

Comment: No it is supposed to be items and I fixed it in both the reducer and the form. @BARNOWL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218536/discussion-between-barnowl-and-saif).